# how to resolve Spring boot @EnableAsync and @Async problem?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

my service:

```
@Service
public class ForgetService{
   @Async
   public CompletableFuture<Object> getTokenService() {
       Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>(8);
       map.put("status", ErrorEnum.TOKEN_SUSSCESS.getStatus());
       map.put("message", ErrorEnum.TOKEN_SUSSCESS.getMessage());
       return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(map); 
   }
}
```

my controller:

```
@RestController
public class ForgetController {
   private final ForgetService forgetService;
   @Autowired
   private ForgetController(ForgetService forgetService) {
       this.forgetService = forgetService;
   }
   @PostMapping(value = "/forget/token")
   @Async
   public CompletableFuture<Object> getTokenController() {
       return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(forgetService.getTokenService());
}
```

}

spring boot application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class ApitestApplication {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(ApitestApplication.class, args);
   }
}
```

---

when i run my application, console log :

The bean 'forgetService' could not be injected as a 'com.apitest.service.ForgetService' because it is a JDK dynamic proxy that implements:
    com.apitest.inf.ForgetServiceInf

Action:

Consider injecting the bean as one of its interfaces or forcing the use of CGLib-based proxies by setting proxyTargetClass=true on @EnableAsync and/or @EnableCaching.

---

**i tried setting 'spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true' in application.properties and setting '@EnableAsync(proxyTargetClass=true), but it's useless,so what's wrong?  how to resolve it?**

Comment: why you need @Async at two layers ? remove Async from controller or service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use below approach, it might help you to fix this issue.

```
@Service
public class ForgetService{
   @Bean("GetTokenService")
   public CompletableFuture<Object> getTokenService() {
       Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>(8);
       map.put("status", ErrorEnum.TOKEN_SUSSCESS.getStatus());
       map.put("message", ErrorEnum.TOKEN_SUSSCESS.getMessage());
       return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(map); 
   }
@RestController
public class ForgetController {
   private final ForgetService forgetService;
   @Autowired
   private ForgetController(ForgetService forgetService) {
       this.forgetService = forgetService;
   }
   @PostMapping(value = "/forget/token")
   @Async("GetTokenService")
   public CompletableFuture<Object> getTokenController() {
       return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(forgetService.getTokenService());
}
```

}